# VBA Knowing if paragraph is an IMAGE

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code:

```
For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If (DocPara.style = "Title 1") Then
        ...
    Else

        (if DocPara is LIST then)
            ...
        (else if DocPara is TABLE then)
            ...
    End If
Next DocPara
```

Is there any way to know if the current paragraph is an IMAGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current paragraph cannot "be" an image because any image is always a character *in* a paragraph OR anchored *to* a paragraph. It would be necessary to count the number of images in / attached to the paragraph's range.

So a paragraph cannot be just an image, it will always contain at least one string character (ANSI 13, the paragraph mark) and may contain an unlimited number besides an image.

Word supports two kinds of images: `InlineShapes` and `Shapes`. The first are handled the same as characters; the latter have text-wrap formatting.

An image formatted with text-wrap may appear to be "in" a paragraph, but is not, and may not even be anchored to the paragraph where it appears. So when the type of image in question is a `Shape` it's not really possible to determine whether there's an image "in" a paragraph by querying the `Paragraph` object.

Here's the code to determine whether an `InlineShape` is in a paragraph and whether any `Shapes` are *anchored to* a paragraph. Based on the way your question is phrased I'm hoping your images are `InlineShapes`...

```
Dim rngPara as Word.Range
Set rngPara = DocPara.Range
If rngPara.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then 'the paragraph contains an image
If rngPara.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then 'an image is anchored to the paragraph
```

Comment: It worked but now i have anoher question which is: Can i get the link/path of this image?

Comment: Could you please post this as a new question @Helloit'sme - with the code you're using. And are you sure the image is linked (IOW you're not asking for the path from which it was inserted, but truly a link)?

Comment: Be aware, too, that you can loop through shapes & inlineshapes without testing each paragraph.